# Gradle alternative to maven <packaging>pom

Tags: maven, gradle, build.gradle

In Gradle multi-module project, how to tell Gradle child module not to build any libs/jars and other dependencies ? Is there some alternatives to maven `<packaging>pom` in Gradle?

Comment: Do you want an answer for Maven or for Gradle? What exactly is your problem? Please _edit the question_ to clarify it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as a result i can specify `jar.enabled = false` and module will not produce any artifacts, however you can still perform custom tasks like compile/copy in this module.